# Octave - fskipl: invalid stream number

Tags: function, for-loop, scanf, octave, fopen

I've got the error message: "Invalid parameter list" from my function, which let Octave open a text file and read it to get input data for my work.

```
function [machNumbers]=readsrm(testfile.txt) 
  fid = fopen('testfile.txt','w');
  fskipl(fid, 3);

  # read number of machnumber
  numMachNumber = fscanf(fid, "%i", 1)
  fscanf(fid, "%s", 5);
  machNumbers = fscanf(fid, "%f", numMachNumber);

  fclose(fid);
endfunction
```

EDIT:

I've updated my code and now I've got this Error: "error: fskipl: invalid stream number = -1".

My code Looks like this:

```
function [machNumbers, weights, altitudes, specificRanges]=readsrm(myfilename)
myfilename = "filename"

  fid = fopen(myfilename,'r');
  fskipl(fid, 3);

fclose(fid);
endfunction
```

EDIT:

The Problems above are solved, thank you. :) Now is the Problem that my for-loop doesn't work correctly. With that code I don't get any Parameters from my text file.

Here is the code:

```
function [machNumbers, weights, altitudes, specificRanges]=readsrm(myfilename)
myfilename = "testfile.txt"

  fid = fopen(myfilename,'r');
  fskipl(fid, 3);

  # read number of machnumber
  numMachNumber = fscanf(fid, "%i", 1)
  fscanf(fid, "%s", 5);
  machNumbers = fscanf(fid, "%f", numMachNumber);

  # read weights
  numWeights = fscanf(fid, "%i", 1);
  fscanf(fid, "%s", 5);
  weights = fscanf(fid, "%f", numWeights)

  # rad altitudes 
  numFl = fscanf(fid, "%i", 1)
  fscanf(fid, "%s", 5);
  altitudes = fscanf(fid, "%f", numFl)

  irrelevantValues = fscanf(fid, "%s", 7)
  for flightLevel= 1:numFl
    for weight = 1:numWeights
      specificRanges(flightLevel, weight, 1:numMachNumber) = fscanf(fid, "%f", numMachNumber);
    endfor
  endfor
  fclose(fid);
endfunction
```

Comment: I haven't used octave, but maybe use `" "` instead of `' '` (like in the rest of your code)?

Comment: and btw, you should never add screenshots of sourceode

Comment: You shouldn't incrementally add more and more questions as soon a your initial question is answered. Instead please bring it into shape so that it might be useful for others and start a new question with the newly rised problem

Answer (score 0):

```
function [machNumbers]=readsrm(testfile.txt)
```

isn't a valid function declaration. You want to give a valid variable name, for example

```
function [machNumbers]=readsrm(myfilename)
  fid = fopen(myfilename,'r');
  ...
```

and then call your function as

```
machNumbers = readsrm("testfile.txt");
```

and of course you apparently want to read from fid, so you have to `fopen` the file with `"r"`(read access), not with `"w"`(write access)

Comment: Hey Andy, thank you for your answer. I've updated my code. But now I got this error.

"error: fskipl: invalid stream number = -1"

`My code Looks like this:

 function [machNumbers, weights, altitudes, specificRanges]=readsrm(myfilename)
myfilename = "filename"

#function [machNumbers, weights, altitudes, specificRanges]=readsrm(filename) 
  fid = fopen(myfilename,'r');
  fskipl(fid, 3);
fclose(fid);
endfunction`

Comment: if `fopen` returns -1 it's an indication that it hasn't found the file. And please try to update your code in the question. There are som repeating parts and I'm unsure if this is just an error in pasting your code here to Stackoverflow or if you really try it this way.

Comment: Yeah, I did it few minutes ago. :)

Comment: I doubt the name of your file is "filename" or is it? And it doesn't make sense to overwrite the function argument myfilename inside the function.

Comment: I declared my variable myfilename with the Name of the file like this: myfilename = "filename.txt". If I don't do that, then I will get the error: "error: 'myfilename' undefined (...)".

Answer (score 0):

For me double quotes around the file name caused my issue.

Try switching to single quotes.